# Customize Image Favorite Voting Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using a script to vote for favorite images: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/favourite-rating-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

I am using two files:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("span.on_img").mouseover(function ()
{
$(this).addClass("over_img");
});
$("span.on_img").mouseout(function ()
{
$(this).removeClass("over_img");
});
});
$(function() {
$(".love").click(function() 
{
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);
$(this).fadeOut(300);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_love.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
parent.html(html);
parent.fadeIn(300);
} 
});   
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

and

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//client ip address
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
//IP-address verification 
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from image_IP where img_id_fk='$id' and  ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);
if($count==0)
{
// Updateing Love Value
$sql = "update images set love=love+1 where img_id='$id'";
mysql_query( $sql);
// Inserting Client IP-address
$sql_in = "insert into image_IP (ip_add,img_id_fk) values ('$ip','$id')";
mysql_query( $sql_in);

$result=mysql_query("select love from images where img_id='$id'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$love=$row['love'];

?>

<span class="on_img" align="left"><?php echo $love; ?></span>
<?php
}
else
{
// Already Loved
echo 'NO !';
}
}
?>
```

By now, the current number of votes for each image is displayed. I would like to
(1) hide this number and just work with messages - like #Click Here to Vote for this image / #Thank you for voring
(2) limit each user to be able to vote only for one image (by now, the user can vote for all the images)

Unfortunately, I am not really familiar with coding and don't have a clue, where to start. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1st point, do this,

```
Replace: 
$love=$row['love'];
With:
$love= 'Thanks for voting';
```

and also in the link given to you, there is a code below this line. "HTML and PHP code. To display records form the images table."
So in that,

```
Replace:
<span class="on_img" align="left"> <?php echo $love; ?> </span>
With:
<span class="on_img" align="left">Click Here to Vote</span>
```

For 2nd point, do this

```
Replace:
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from image_IP where img_id_fk='$id' and  ip_add='$ip'");
With:
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from image_IP where ip_add='$ip'");
```

Comment: perfectly :) Perhaps you can give me an other hint on how to display the images in two columns? By now, they are displayed among each other

Comment: Use HTML Tables for that. Or Replace `<img src='<?php echo $img_url; ?>' />` with `<img class="votingimages" src='<?php echo $img_url; ?>' />` and in your css add `.votingimages { display:inline; float:left; }` Should Work. If doesn't google for putting images inline.

Comment: thanks :) If somebody is looking for the same:
<div style="width:1050px" >
[...]
<div class="votingimages ">
<div style="margin-bottom:30px">
<div class="box" align="left">
<a href="#" class="love" id="<?php echo $img_id; ?>">
<span class="on_img" align="left"> Click Here to Vote </span> 
</a>
</div>
<img src='<?php echo $img_url; ?>' />
</div>
</div>

.votingimages
{
display:inline;
float:left;
padding-right:25px;
}

Comment: Glad you were able to get it to work. And Yes, actually it had to be in a div, My bad... Pretty tired today, should get my mind some rest. Doing silly mistakes ~_~

Answer (score 0):

**You can change the number to a custom message easily. Just change this following line on php file**

```
<span class="on_img" align="left"><?php echo $love; ?></span>
```

**with**

```
<span class="on_img" align="left"> #Click Here to Vote for this image / #Thank you for voring</span>
```

But second change is more hard. At first you need to make a subscribe or user account system. Also you can use HTML data storage technology.